# CMake install to /bin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I have a directory structure in CMake as follows:

```
root
    CMakeLists.txt
    subproject_folder
        my_dll_library
        CMakeLists.txt
            src
                source1.cpp
                source2.cpp
            inc
                library.h
            CMakeLists.txt
        library_demo
            src
                demo.cpp
            CMakeLists.txt
    build
    bin
```

My root CmakeLists.txt contains this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory(subproject_folder)
if(MSVC)
# Force to always compile with W4
    if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES "/W[0-4]")
            string(REGEX REPLACE "/W[0-4]" "/W4" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
    else()
            set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
endif()
    elseif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    # Update if necessary
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wno-long-long -pedantic")
    endif()
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

The CMakeLists in the subproject folder just contains

```
add_subdirectory(my_dll_library)
add_subdirectory(library_demo)
```

The CMakeLists in the library_demo folder contains

```
project(library_demo)
add_executable(librarydemo src/demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(librarydemo my_dll_library)
install(TARGETS librarydemo DESTINATION bin)
```

The CMakeLists in the my_dll_library folder contains

```
add_library(lib_zaber SHARED src/source1.cpp src/source2.cpp)
install(TARGETS lib_zaber DESTINATION bin)
```

I want to have the demo executable and the library DLL copied to the bin folder, but it isn't working.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set those variables too:

```
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR
CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR
```

There's a whole list of variables you could try here:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: @Tim There are too many other directories you can try to change. You have a full list to try. If anything is going to work, it should be within that list. I did that before but I don't have the source anymore, unfortunately. Good luck!

Comment: EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH is the cmake variable for executables and dynamic libraries path. Set it before add_executable(...)/add_library(...) with the path you need.

Comment: In general, avoid setting variables like `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`. CMake sets these for the benefit of your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
install(.. DESTINATION <dir>)
```

installs to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/<dir>`.

You need to set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` either in the CMakeLists.txt or when calling `cmake`:

```
cmake ... -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<dir>
```